# Upgrading Python pip uninstalls old version but doesn’t install the new one

Tags: pip, python3

After installing some new packages using Python's `pip`, I received a message saying that I should consider upgrading its version:

```
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I did it typing the command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

But the computer seemed to have uninstalled the old version of `pip` (18.1) and not installed the new one (19.0.1).

I have installed winpython again in my portable device and also the packages of my interest, but I don't know how I can upgrade pip without having the same problem again.

At the time that I tried to upgrade `pip` and it failed, I had gotten a message that maybe it was a user permission problem. But I don't know how I can check whether it is the problem, and I don't understand why this may be a problem since the installation of other packages was just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this kind of mess myself on Windows. Try this:

First figure out the location for the Python pip current folder in explorer,
copy it.

If you fail to locate the folder, hit the “Start” button and type `cmd` then in `cmd` type:

```
pip --version
```

Or:

```
pip -V
```

^ Using any one of these will give you the location with the version number.

Copy the location, type `cd`

And then paste the location you found and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then it'll change the directory to that path, and then type:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then type:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Or:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

It will then show the info of what’s happening.

And then it’ll install the new version if current version is old and that’s it.

Comment: None of these worked. It says "no module named pip".